# Is it good for an iPad application to have everything in local?

Tags: ipad, pdf, video, image

I develop an iPad application for a company. They want to use the application to show media, like pdf docs, pictures, video. They want one application for everything.
So I use a TabBar Application, each TabBar display a media, like pictures gallery, video gallery. The application is pretty big. And now the application is running slowly. The display of pdf is not smooth, the swich of tab takes time. I use the local data because I can use internet for the application, it needs to works everywhere without wifi.
So my question, is it a good idea to put everything in the same application? I add all my media in the xcode project.
Is the iPad good for displaying video, pdfs, pictures in the same application ? I want something smooth, but to much data for the memory kills my application. What ways I need to take ? Do you have ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not purging media from memory when it is no longer used.

Make sure to release media related objects that are not immediately in use. Images in particular eat memory very quickly because all the data associated with an image has to been in memory. Unlike a PDF or audio file which can be read in as needed.

Users will expect and tolerate some slight delay switching from media type to media type because they experience that will all other apps and other forms of software. What they don't tolerate is slow performance while actively using a piece of media e.g. slow scrolling in a PDF file.

Comment: Thanks for the respond.
I verify with Instrument if all my media is released. It seems good. My application doesn't go slowler and slower during the time.

Even I display one pdf, if the pdf is big like more than 10 pages, the scrolling is slow. Maybe the UIWebView is not the best way to display pdf with lots of pages.

Or maybe I displayed to much media via Interface Builder, and I don't know how I can save memory from a TabBar View when I am not using it...

Comment: Webviews can be slow to display PDFs. If you have a lot of PDFs I would recommend using a dedicated PDF view. There are a few libraries out there for such work. I'm not sure what you mean by " I displayed to much media via Interface Builder". It doesn't sound like you are have memory issues. If you haven't done a lot of mobile work, your sense of app speed may be off because you are used to more powerful desktop/laptops. Mobile devices have less horsepower.  If it starts out slow and stays slow then its probably a design problem. You might need to use threads/operations to speed things up.